# How much traffic can a free Heroku hosted site can handle?

Tags: web-hosting, server, heroku

I have a single page website with is hosted on Heroku. I want to know how much traffic my Heroku account can handle before it crashes. My page contain 1 image, 1 input field, 2 buttons and few link. The page size is 13kb.

Can someone tell how much Traffic/visitors it can handle without crashing. The number can be visitors/day.

Comment: You have given no details about the server so we can't help you.  If you want a knowledgeable person to answer, you should probably ask Heroku support.

Comment: @steve when this was asked on Stack Overflow, it was clear that it was for a free-level Heroku account. I edited the question to add that clarity here. That seems like a standard enough setup that it should be answerable.